# Export/Save? Docker container on Linux to hard drive in order to Import/Load it in Windows 10 without Hyper-V?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, hyper-v

I have a large container that I cannot get via network (due to shitty internet connection), so I need a way to export that container to hard drive in order to use it on my Windows machine. So basically:

1. Docker container running on Linux ->
2. Export/Save on hard drive ->
3. Import/Load on Windows ->
4. Run on Windows 10 with/without Hyper-V?

How can I achieve this? I'm confused about Export/Import and Load/Save? Can you give full command line commands?

Let's assume this is my container:

```
Container ID: 638aac32ff06
Image: registry.mycompany.com/db:latest
Ports: 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
Name: db
```

Comment: I assume you want the image and not move a running container?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Containers are created under Linux won't work under clear Windows. I hope in the future when MS will make complite release Ubuntu subsystem under Windows it will be possible. But not now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems possible now! (which is quite amazing!)
On Linux (source machine) run:

```
docker save {container_name} -o {path_to_save}.tar
```

Then, on Windows (target machine) run:

```
docker load -i {path_to_save}.tar
```

That's all! (Be sure docker desktop is set to use Linux containers from tray icon menu)